# Github-like routes in ServiceStack

Tags: routes, servicestack

Is it possible to define Github-like routes in ServiceStack?  I would like to define a REST api like:

```
home                   /
account home           /{account}
project detail         /{account}/{project}
project issues index   /{account}/{project}/issues
project issues detail  /{account}/{project}/issues/1
```

I have tried:

```cs
[Route("/{Account}"]
public class GetAccount : IReturn<AccountDto> {
    public string Account { get; set; }
}

[Route("/{Account}/{Project}"]
public class GetProject : IReturn<ProjectDto> {
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
}

// DTOs for issues, etc...
```

The above DTOs throw this NotSupportedException on startup:

```
RestPath '/{Account}' on Type 'GetAccount' is not Valid
```

It seems pretty clear that ServiceStack 4 isn't supposed to support this use case (hence the NotSupportedException).

I'm just wondering if there is a way I can define custom routing (or write my own routing) so this scenario will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the special [FallbackRoute can handle routes from the root path](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route) like `/{Account}` and as it matches any string from the root path only one `[FallbackRoute]` can be defined.

Routes that contain no literal text to be able to match on like `/{Account}/{Project}` are also invalid. What you can do instead is have a Fallback Service that matches all unmatched routes and re-route the request based on how many components in the path info, e.g:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{Path*}")] //matches all unmatched routes
public class RootPathRoutes
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class GetAccount : IReturn<Account>
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
}

public class GetProject : IReturn<Project>
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Fallback Service you can use the components in the Path Info to call the desired service, e.g:

```
public class GitHubServices : Service
{
    public object Any(RootPathRoutes request)
    {
        if (request.Path != null)
        {
            var parts = request.Path.Split('/');
            if (parts.Length == 1)
                return Any(new GetAccount { Account = parts[0] });
            if (parts.Length == 2)
                return Any(new GetProject { Account = parts[0], Project = parts[1] });
        }

        return request; //passed to default page i.e. default.cshtml 
        //return HttpResult.Redirect("/metadata"); //e.g. of redirect response
    }

    public object Any(GetAccount request)
    {
        return new Account { Name = request.Account };
    }

    public object Any(GetProject request)
    {
        return new Project {
            Account = request.Account,
            Name = request.Project,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. For my final architecture I decided to use simpler routes for all my DTOs (accounts: /a/{Id}/{NameSlug}, projects: /p/{Id}/{NameSlug}) and a fallback route for my web client with the URL scheme above (/{account}/{project}).  Works well so far!